# How to use the form-datalist to enter the data in db through PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

There is a field in db called "Amount".

I try to create a field called `Donation Amount` in the html form .This amount can be selected from the datalist or entered. But I cannot see the datalist and the value cannot be inputted to the db now . How should I tackle this problem ?

```
    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $CName = $Address = $Phone = $Amount= $Purpose= $Ticket = "";
    $CName_err = $Address_err = $Phone_err = $Amount_err = $Purpose_err = $Ticket_err="";
    ....
//datalist
    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($Amount_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">                             
    <label>*Donation Amount</label>                    
    <input type="text" name="Amount" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $Amount; ?>">    
    <datalist id="Amount" >
    <option value="100">
    <option value="300">
    <option value="500">
    <option value="1000">
    </datalist>  
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $Amount_err; ?></span>
     </div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? The datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

Comment: @MattBlack I use Chrome .I just see a blank field of input text field